# Port Python-DocX function to C#

Tags: c#, python, json, parsing, ms-word

I have a Python function, to take a MSWord document as an input, as well as a section heading/number, and return the table from that section as a JSON object.

Need to convert this python function over to C#, and use the Aspose.Words for .NET library.

Here is the code:

```
    from __future__ import (
    absolute_import, division, print_function, unicode_literals
)

import json
from docx import Document
from docx.document import Document as _Document
from docx.oxml.text.paragraph import CT_P
from docx.oxml.text.run import CT_R
from docx.oxml.table import CT_Tbl
from docx.table import _Cell, Table
from docx.text.paragraph import Paragraph
from docx.text.run import Run
#import datetime
import sys, traceback
import win_unicode_console
from colorama import init
from colorama import Fore, Back, Style


#outputFile = open('Document-ToJSON.csv', 'w', newline='\n')
#outputWriter = csv.writer(outputFile)

gblDocTree = []
gblDocListNumber = []
gblRowCols = {}


def init_myGlobals():
    #Reinitialize Global Variables
    #init()
    win_unicode_console.enable()
    init()
    global gblDocTree
    gblDocTree = []
    global gblDocListNumber
    gblDocListNumber = []
    global gblRowCols
    gblRowCols = {}
    return

class tblparam():
    def __init__(self,param):
        self.param = param

def get_num(x):
    return int(''.join(ele for ele in x if ele.isdigit()))

def add_RowCol(rowNumber, rowList):
    global gblRowCols
    gblRowCols[rowNumber] = rowList
    return

def add_to_sectionnumber(myLocation):
    global gblDocListNumber
    myInt = myLocation - 1

    if myLocation > len(gblDocListNumber) or len(gblDocListNumber) == 0:
        #initializing
        gblDocListNumber.append(1)
    elif len(gblDocListNumber) == myLocation:
        #if total array len is equal to current heading depth
        #do this
        gblDocListNumber[myInt] = gblDocListNumber[myInt] + 1
    #elif myLocation == 1:
    #   del gblDocListNumber[0:]
    #   gblDocListNumber[0] = gblDocListNumber[0] + 1
    elif len(gblDocListNumber) > myLocation:
        #x = len(gblDocListNumber) - myLocation
        #print("myLocation:{0}, myListCount:{1}".format(myLocation, len(gblDocListNumber)))
        #Eliminate everything from
        del gblDocListNumber[myLocation:]
        gblDocListNumber[myLocation - 1] = gblDocListNumber[myLocation - 1] + 1
    return

def add_to_hierarchy(myHeading, myLocation):
    #Create a String Array holding the Paragraph
    #Names, and appending them to previous levels
    #Heading1 > SubHeading2 > SubHeading3
    global gblDocTree
    myInt = myLocation - 1
    if myLocation > len(gblDocTree) or len(gblDocTree) == 0:
        gblDocTree.append(myHeading)
    elif len(gblDocTree) == myLocation:
        gblDocTree[myInt] = myHeading
    elif myLocation == 1:
        del gblDocTree[:]
        gblDocTree.append(myHeading)
    elif len(gblDocTree) > myLocation:
        x = len(gblDocTree) - myLocation
        #print("i'm going to remove -{0}".format(x))
        del gblDocTree[myLocation - 1:]
        gblDocTree.append(myHeading)
    return

def iter_block_items(parent):
    #"""
    #Generate a reference to each paragraph and table child within *parent*,
    #in document order. Each returned value is an instance of either Table or
    #Paragraph. *parent* would most commonly be a reference to a main
    #Document object, but also works for a _Cell object, which itself can
    #contain paragraphs and tables.
    #"""
    if isinstance(parent, _Document):
        parent_elm = parent.element.body
        #print(parent_elm.xml)
    elif isinstance(parent, _Cell):
        parent_elm = parent._tc
    else:
        raise ValueError("something's not right")

    for child in parent_elm.iterchildren():
        if isinstance(child, CT_P):
            yield Paragraph(child, parent)
        elif isinstance(child, CT_Tbl):
            yield Table(child, parent)
        #elif isinstance(child, CT_R):
        #   yield Run(child, parent)

def parseDocX(mydocumentfullpath, startSection):

    init_myGlobals()    #Initialize 

    #Setup variables#
    myDoc = mydocumentfullpath
#   f = open(outputCSVPath, 'w', newline='')    #Python 3, newline='' eliminates extra newlines' in output
    startSectSet = True
    try:

        document = Document(myDoc)
        prvHeader = ''
        headerLst = ['Heading 1',
                        'Heading 2', 'Heading 3', 'Heading 4',
                        'Heading 5', 'Heading 6', 'Heading 7',
                        'Heading 8', 'Heading 9',
                        'Egemin1', 'Egemin2', 'Egemin3', 'Egemin4',
                        'Egemin5', 'Egemin6', 'Egemin7', 'Egemin8',
                        'Egemin9', 'Egemin10', 'Egemin11', 'Egemin12']
        valNext = False
        prvIntHeadLv = 0
        curHeadIntLv = 0
        curHeadNm = ''
        curListNm = ''
        myIntValName = ''
        myPropCnt = 0
        sectionJSON = {}
        paraText = ''

        for block in iter_block_items(document):
            #print(block.text if isinstance(block, Paragraph) else '<table>')
            #print('************************')
            #print('NEW LOOP')
            if isinstance(block, Paragraph):
                #print('In Paragraph')
                #for myRun in block.runs:
                #   print('Got Runs ?')
                #   print('Run Text :: {0}'.format(myRun.text))
                    #print('Style :: {0}'.format(myRun.style.name))
                #print(block.runs.text)
                #print(block.text)
                #print(block.style.name)
                if block.style.name in headerLst:

                    #New Document Header, so new Section
                    sectionJSON = {}    #Reset
                    paraText = ''

                    #Paragraphs contain all doc information.
                    #Using the above array, we're checking for the most commonly used
                    #Section/Paragrah Headers
                    #So we can differentiate what data we are actually processing
                    curHeadIntLv = get_num(block.style.name)    
                    add_to_hierarchy(block.text.strip().lower(), curHeadIntLv)

#BOUTIFY CODE

                    if len(block.text.strip().lower())>0:
                        add_to_sectionnumber(curHeadIntLv)
                    curListNm = '.'.join(map(str, gblDocListNumber))
                    curHeadNm = "%s %s" % (curListNm, block.text.strip())

                    #Check if Current Section is greater than required Start
                    if(startSectSet and curListNm!=''):
                        sectionHeading = curHeadNm.lstrip().split(" ")[0]   #Use Full Paragraph Header String, to ID true section number
                        curListTuple = tuple([int(x) for x in sectionHeading.split('.')])
                        reqStartTuple = tuple([int(x) for x in startSection.split('.')])
                        if (curListTuple < reqStartTuple):
                            continue    #Skip iteration
                        elif (curListTuple > reqStartTuple):
                            break   #Exit

                    if curHeadIntLv == 1 or prvIntHeadLv == 0:
                        #curHeadNm = block.text.strip().lower()
                        prvIntHeadLv = curHeadIntLv

                    elif curHeadIntLv == prvIntHeadLv:
                        prvIntHeadLv = curHeadIntLv
                        continue

                    elif curHeadIntLv > prvIntHeadLv:
                        prvIntHeadLv = curHeadIntLv
                        continue

                    else:
                        #curHeadNm = block.text.strip().lower()
                        prvIntHeadLv = curHeadIntLv
                        continue
                else:
                    curParaText = block.text.strip().lower()
                    paraText += block.text.strip().lower().replace("'", "''")

            elif isinstance(block, Table):  #process table rows, for interesting data

            #Check if Current Section is greater than required Start
                if(startSectSet and curListNm!=''):
                    sectionHeading = curHeadNm.lstrip().split(" ")[0]   #Use Full Paragraph Header String, to ID true section number
                    curListTuple = tuple([int(x) for x in sectionHeading.split('.')])
                    reqStartTuple = tuple([int(x) for x in startSection.split('.')])
                    if (curListTuple < reqStartTuple):
                        continue    #Skip iteration
                    elif (curListTuple > reqStartTuple):
                        break   #exit
                else:
                    continue        
                #Assuming if @ table, then paragraph Text is all captured
                #sectionJSON.update({"ParagraphText":paraText})

                i = 0

                if curHeadNm!='':
                    #print("Good Heading")
                    #Try and get the Heading Number
                    sectionHeading = curHeadNm.lstrip().split(" ")[0]
                    #print("Section Check ; {0}".format(sectionHeading))
                else:
                    #print("Empty Heading")
                    continue

                rowsArray = []
                headerArray = []
                #Process Table, row by row
                for row in block.rows:
                    #print('Processing section {0}'.format(sectionHeading))
                    i += 1
                    myCell = 0
                    JSONrow = {}
                    rstList = []
                    rowStringify = []
                    if i==1:
                        for row_cell in row.cells:
                            headerArray.append(row_cell.text.strip().lower().replace("'", "''"))
                            continue #Start proper table loop
                    else:
#                   for row_cell in row.cells:
#                       rstList.append(row_cell.text.strip().lower().replace("'", "''"))
                        for x in range(len(headerArray)):
                            #print('Iteration {0}'.format(x))
                            #print(row.cells[x].text.strip().lower())
                            rowStringify.append("\"" + headerArray[x] + "\"" + ":" + "\"" + row.cells[x].text.strip().lower().replace("'", "''") + "\"")
                        #Create JSON object, with Array of Columns as Value
                        myStr = ("{" + (','.join(map(str, rowStringify))) + "}")
                        print(u"{}".format(myStr))
                        #JSONrow = json.loads(myStr.replace('\r', '\\r').replace('\n', '\\n'))
                        JSONrow = json.loads(u"{}".format(myStr))
                        rowsArray.append(JSONrow)   #Now, add JSONrow back to array object

                sectionJSON.update({"Rows":rowsArray})
                break   #end now, after fully processing table
                #print(json.dumps(sectionJSON, indent=4, sort_keys=True))

                #writer = csv.writer(f, delimiter=',')
                #writer.writerow([sectionHeading, json.dumps(sectionJSON)])
                #now, back to start

    except IOError as e:
        print ('I/O error({0}): {1}'.format(e.errno, e.strerror))
#       traceback.print_exc()
        #return 1
    except ValueError:
        print ('Could not convert data to an integer. {0} :: {1}'.format(sys.exc_info()[0], sys.exc_info()[1]))
#       traceback.print_exc()
        #return 1
    except :
        print ('Unexpected error: {0} :: {1}'.format(sys.exc_info()[0], sys.exc_info()[1]))
        traceback.print_exc()
        #return 1
    finally:
        #f.close()
        win_unicode_console.disable()
        return json.dumps(sectionJSON,sort_keys=True)
#       globals().clear()
        #return 0

#if __name__=='__main__':
#   sys.exit(main(sys.argv[1], sys.argv[2]))
```

Link to Python Function in pastebin if needed : https://pastebin.com/vrHkk9s0

Answer (score 0):

There is no Python to C# conversion service that I know of.

You can however run [Python](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/charlie/2009/10/25/running-ironpython-scripts-from-a-c-4-0-program/) from within your .Net App.

Using IronPython you can actually integrate .Net Code into your Python script and for example set a string property from you Python script.

Alternately, you can just run your Python script from C# and get the result of the python function.

You can try something like this:

```
static void Main()
{
    var ipy = Python.CreateRuntime();
    dynamic parser = ipy.UseFile("WordParser.py");
    string docPath = "C:\\SomeFolder\\SomeWord.Docx";
    var result = parser.parseDocX(docPath,"somesection);
}
```

Comment: hi, thanks for the reply, i liked your idea, i will try first implementing it. what i want is a code written in c# that do the same like my Python code.